# How to see error when VS code yellow highlights a line?

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code, mobile

I just started programming in flutter and I keep getting these types of errors with the yellow highlight over a line. The highlight goes away if I pressed the green restart button and as long as the issue is gone. The problem is that sometimes I will just retype the yellow-highlighted code in a different order and it begins to work again. So far I have been able to fix the issues, but it's really annoying because I have to constantly guess and check and retype, praying on my luck to fix it. Is there a way I could actually see the error message? I'm pretty sure it's minor, since I copy and pasted this straight from official documentation.

[image]

Edit: I realized that when I right click on the yellow arrow, it shows "run to line" and I can run the code without issues. However, the yellow arrow reappears from time to time, seemingly randomly.

Comment: it appears whenever the debugger stops, see the controls in the upper right

Comment: Why would the debugger stop? I'm not pressing the stop button and I do press reload on my controls. It seems like there is an issue, but I can't seem to catch it.

Comment: you must ask this with the dart debugger, the image shows the debugger has found a breakpoint